# Using multiple inputs for raw_input python

Tags: python, input, raw-input

Hi this is my first question. I started working on learning python this week and I started making simple programs. I started making a raw_input program, so the console asks a question like "Hi how are you?" and no matter what you respond with it would say the same thing. Is there a way I could make it so that if I say good it would say "Awesome!..." then ask another question like "Awesome! How old are you?" Something like that? This is my simple code so far.

```
print "Hello! THis is a simple program created by myselF! It will ask a variety of simple questions!"

how_are_you = raw_input("How are you?")
print how_are_you

age = raw_input("Good, glad to hear it! How old are you?") # Or "Aw thats not good hopefully this will change that. blah blah blah.
print age
```

Comment: Subtle. This could easily go from a few lines of code to some AI project.

Comment: Yes, you could do that, but it would probably get very complex very quickly and is not a good subject for a SO question. I would start with a dictionary mapping something that can match a user's input (e.g. using a regular expression or just something simple like `'good' in response.lower()`) to the next action the "bot" should take (e.g. `print 'Awesome!'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, go ahead and take a look at [if statements, and flow of control](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html). In short, `if` lets you do some things if a condition is true. In this example, it could be something like:

```
how_are_you = raw_input("How are you? ")
if how_are_you == 'good':
    print 'Awesome!'
```

You can also use `else` or `elif` to have multiple branches:

```
how_are_you = raw_input("How are you? ")
if how_are_you == 'good':
    print 'Awesome!'
elif how_are_you == 'great':
    print 'Fantastic!'
else: # if how_are_you is anything except 'good' or 'great'.
    print "that's not so good..."
```

And there's much, much more with making sure sensical things work (if the user types "Good" this chunk won't catch it- you'd need to use the .lower() functionality to compare regardless of case, or `in` to verify that punctuation won't kill it.). if...elif...else chains can be arbitrarily long, so you can have as many options and unique responses.

You can also chain conditions with `and` and `or` if you want to use the same response for multiple inputs.